# Settings Changed Notification In Subclass Of IASKAppSettingsViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, inappsettingskit

I have a subclass of IASKAppSettingsViewController that I, of course, use to display and handle various events for the settings I present to the user.
In this subclass, I am trying to receive the notification that settings were changed by adding this line to `-(void)viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(settingsChanged:) name:kIASKAppSettingChanged object:nil];
```

Problem is that the method, settingsChanged, is never being called. I figure that there is some other way of doing this or I am doing something wrong here. This procedure does work for me in other classes, so I assume there is something special about IASKAppSettingsViewController that is preventing this from working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT #1**

Received a message from Future Tap via GitHub and he asked me to check the sample app.  I did and the sample app does not use a subclass of IASKAppSettingsViewController.  I have since added another `addObserver` and that is also not being called.  I verified that both `addObserver` calls are being executed, so that is not the cause.

**EDIT #2**

It appears that something is terribly amiss in my app.  I have multiple classes that observe this notification and they all use the same name for the method to be called (settingsChanged).  When I Command-click the name of the method in one `addObserver` call, Xcode brings me to another class' settingsChanged method.  This is probably what is causing some of my observer methods not to get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Future Tap, we discovered that `IASKAppSettingsViewController' was removing all observers when the view disappeared.  This was causing the observers that I set up to be removed and, thus, not be called.  The code has been fixed and my problem is solved.